# Java sockets, simple multiplayer game, sending data

Tags: java, sockets, multiplayer

so I'm working on a really simple multiplayer Java game, just one where you click on the screen and your player moves to that spot in a straight line, and show all the other connected players your players movement, here are the three classes:

Bots:

```
import java.applet.Applet;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import java.util.ArrayList;


public class Bots extends Applet implements MouseListener, Runnable{

Thread gameLoop;
ArrayList<Player> players = new ArrayList<Player>();

//Socket stuff for multiplayer client
final static String SERVER_ADDR = "localhost";
final static int SERVER_PORT = 1025;
static Socket socket;
static volatile BufferedReader br;
static PrintWriter pw;


//Double buffer stuff
Graphics g; 
Image offscreen;
Dimension dim;

@Override
public void run() {
    //Starts the main game loop
    Thread t = Thread.currentThread();
    //Checks to see if the thread is alive
    while (t == gameLoop){
        try{
        Thread.sleep(1000/60);
        //Repaints the screen
        players.get(0).move();
        repaint();

        if (socket != null){
            sendMove();
        }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}

public void start(){
    gameLoop = new Thread(this);
    gameLoop.start();
}

public void stop(){
    gameLoop = null;
}

public void init(){
    this.setSize(640,480);
    dim = this.getSize();

    addMouseListener(this);

    //More double buffer stuff
    offscreen = createImage(this.getSize().width,this.getSize().height);
    g = offscreen.getGraphics();

    //Adds the initial player
    players.add(new Player(320,240,8,8,"Jeremy"));
    multiplayer();
}

public void paint(Graphics bufferGraphics){
    g = offscreen.getGraphics(); 
    g.clearRect(0,0,dim.width,dim.height);

    g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    for (Player player: players){
        g.fillOval(player.x, player.y, player.width, player.height);
    }

    bufferGraphics.drawImage(offscreen,0,0,this);
}

public void multiplayer(){

    try {
        socket = new Socket(SERVER_ADDR, SERVER_PORT);
        InputStreamReader isr;
        isr = new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream());
        br = new BufferedReader(isr);
        pw = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    multiplayerThread();

}

public void sendMove(){
    //pw.println(players.get(0).name+":X"+players.get(0).x+":Y"+players.get(0).y);
}

public void multiplayerThread(){
    new Thread(){
        public void run() { 
            String line;
             try {
                while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    boolean newClient = true;
                    for (Player player: players){
                        if (line.startsWith(player.name)){
                            if (line.startsWith(players.get(0).name)){
                                //Do nothing
                                newClient = false;
                            } else {
                                String[] tempLine = line.split(":");
                                player.x = Integer.parseInt(tempLine[1].substring(1));
                                player.y = Integer.parseInt(tempLine[2].substring(1));
                                newClient = false;
                            }
                        }
                        System.out.println(line);
                    }
                    if (newClient && !line.contains("Welcome")){
                        String[] tempLine = line.split(":");
                        players.add(new Player (Integer.parseInt(tempLine[1].substring(1)),Integer.parseInt(tempLine[2].substring(1)),8,8,tempLine[0].substring(0)));
                    }

                }
             }
             catch (IOException ioe) {
             }
        }
    }.start();
}
@Override
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent me) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void mouseExited(MouseEvent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent me) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    players.get(0).x2 = me.getX();
    players.get(0).y2 = me.getY();
    players.get(0).calculateMove();
}

@Override
public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

public void update(Graphics g) 
{ 
     paint(g); 
}
}
```

Player class:

```
    import java.awt.Rectangle;


public class Player {

    public String name;
    public int x;
    public int y;
    public int width;
    public int height;

    public int x2;
    public int y2;
    public int longest;
    public int numerator;
    public int shortest;
    public int dx1,dy1,dx2,dy2;
    public boolean moving;

    public Player(int x, int y, int width, int height, String name) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.x2 = x;
        this.y2 =y;
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Rectangle getBounds(){
        Rectangle r;
        r = new Rectangle(x - width/2, y-height/2,width,height);
        return r;
    }

    public void move(){
        if (this.x2 != this.x && this.y2 != this.y){
            this.numerator += this.shortest ;
            if (!(this.numerator<this.longest)) {
                this.numerator -= this.longest ;
                this.x += this.dx1 ;
                this.y += this.dy1 ;
            } else {
                this.x += this.dx2 ;
                this.y += this.dy2 ;
            }
            this.moving = false;

        }
    }

    public void calculateMove(){
         int w = x2 - x ;
            int h = y2 - y ;
            int dx1 = 0, dy1 = 0, dx2 = 0, dy2 = 0 ;
            if (w<0) dx1 = -1 ; else if (w>0) dx1 = 1 ;
            if (h<0) dy1 = -1 ; else if (h>0) dy1 = 1 ;
            if (w<0) dx2 = -1 ; else if (w>0) dx2 = 1 ;
            int longest = Math.abs(w) ;
            int shortest = Math.abs(h) ;
            if (!(longest>shortest)) {
                longest = Math.abs(h) ;
                shortest = Math.abs(w) ;
                if (h<0) dy2 = -1 ; else if (h>0) dy2 = 1 ;
                dx2 = 0 ;            
            }
            this.shortest = shortest;
            this.longest = longest;
            this.numerator = longest >> 1 ;
            this.dx1 = dx1;
            this.dy1 = dy1;
            this.dx2 = dx2;
            this.dy2 = dy2;
            this.moving = true;
            }

}
```

And finally my BotsServer class:

```
    import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

class BotsServer
{
   private final static int PORT_NO = 1025;
   private ServerSocket listener;
   private List<Connection> clients;
   BotsServer() throws IOException
   {
      listener = new ServerSocket(PORT_NO);
      clients = new ArrayList<Connection>();
      System.out.println("listening on port "+PORT_NO);
   }
   void runServer()
   {
      try
      {
         while (true)
         {
            Socket socket = listener.accept();
            System.out.println("accepted connection");
            Connection con = new Connection(socket);
            synchronized(clients)
            {
               clients.add(con);
               con.start();
               con.send("Welcome!");
            }
         }
      }
      catch (IOException ioe)
      {
         System.err.println("I/O error: "+ioe.getMessage());
         return;
      }
   }
   private class Connection extends Thread
   {
      private volatile BufferedReader br;
      private volatile PrintWriter pw;
      private String clientName;
      Connection(Socket s) throws IOException
      {
         br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));
         pw = new PrintWriter(s.getOutputStream(), true);
      }
      @Override
      public void run()
      {
         System.out.println("test");
         String line;
         try
         {
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null){
                System.out.println(line);
               send(line);
            }
         }
         catch (IOException ioe)
         {
            System.err.println("I/O error: "+ioe.getMessage());
         }
         finally
         {
            synchronized(clients)
            {
               clients.remove(this);
            }
         }

      }

      private void send(String message)
      {
         pw.println(message);
      }

   }
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      try
      {
         System.out.println("ChatServer starting");
         new BotsServer().runServer();
      }
      catch (IOException ioe)
      {
         System.err.println("unable to create server socket");
      }
   }
}
```

The problem I believe is in the BotsServer class, I put:

```
System.out.println("test");
```

in the run but it is only ever getting called when clients first connect, should it be looping? Any help is great! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`BotServer.Connection` is a `Thread`.  The `run` method of a `Thread` is only called once.  Your test print is inside `run()` but not inside any loop, so it will only get printed once per `BotServer.Connection` you `start()`.  So the behavior you are seeing makes sense to me.  Why do you think it should loop?